# Visual Web Part cannot be found or is not registered as safe, and isn't being added to web.config

Tags: development, web-part, visual-studio, visual-web-part

I'm new to SharePoint development, and I'm making a basic Visual Web Part with Visual Studio 2015, which currently only displays a header. It successfully builds and deploys, however the SharePoint 2016 site returns the error:

`A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The Type <Namespace>.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1, ..., PublicKeyToken=<#> could not be found or is not registered as safe.`

The Properties window of the Web Part has all the correct information, and after some digging I've discovered that the web.config file doesn't update correctly. In [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dbbca485-7707-4d29-986a-40526ec03872/problem-with-webpart-as-a-safe-control?forum=sharepointadminprevious), examining a similar error, the chosen answer explains that the Manifest.xml file handles the web.config updating, and I've noticed that VS hasn't (and I suspect won't) make this file for me.

Is there a fix in Visual Studio that I can correct to have it make this file for me, or do I have to make this manually? If I do have to make the Manifest manually, what does it consist of?

Comment: Sounds like the DLLs are not being sent to the GAC.  Is the a farm of sandbox solution?

Comment: It is a farm solution.

Answer (score 1):

When webpart deployed successfully, there will be a SafeControl map to web part.

For example:

[image]

```
<SafeControl Assembly="SP2016Project, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d20aa9b415aaf50" Namespace="SP2016Project.FirstVisualWebPart" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
```

If you can't find this in your web.config(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\port), you could try to register it manually.[How to get assembly PublicKeyToken](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wriju/2008/07/01/how-to-find-public-key-token-for-a-net-dll-or-assembly/)

Comment: The Safe Control Entries for the project are exactly as above. While I can manually add the VisualWebPart to the Safe Control, I would prefer not to do this every time I create one. If the Safe Control Entries are correct, why would the WebPart not be added to the web.config?